# About Drag and Drop functionality in swing

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I have one Button name with DATE and another is Text-field in one frame. i want to make a program in a such a way that,when i drag the this button in text-field at that time in text-field,SYSTEM DATE OF A SYSTEM will be print.Any one can solve it? if yes then help me.

Comment: Start by going through the [**Drag and Drop**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/index.html) tutorial. After you have attempted something, if it doesn't work, let us know what the problem is, and we will try to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

ButtonObject.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

```
    Date date = new Date();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");

    TextfieldObject.setText(sdf.format(date));

   }
```

});